# How to get snowflake host and port number to create connection in SAP Analytics Cloud?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

The SAP Analytics Cloud's Snowflake Connector needs these details for setting up a Snowflake connection

[[image]

How can I get these details from Snowflake?

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/05/14/connecting-analytics-cloud-to-snowflake-import-mode/)

Comment: What tool are you trying to connect with?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you're attempting to configure [SAP Analytics Cloud's Snowflake Connector](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/05/14/connecting-analytics-cloud-to-snowflake-import-mode/).

The host and port of your Snowflake account (also known as its deployment URL) can be taken from the URL you use to connect to Snowflake's Web UI. Here's an example:

[image: screenshot depicting a highlighted snowflake account URL in a browser window]

For the above URL, the input in the `Server` field of the form will be `mzf0194.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com:443` (the `443` port number is the default HTTPS port that Snowflake serves on).

Or alternatively, if you have access to any other Snowflake connected application (such as `SnowSQL`, etc.) that lets you run a SQL query, run the following to extract it:

```sql
select t.value:host || ':443' snowflake
from table(flatten(parse_json(system$whitelist()))) t
where t.value:type = 'SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT';
```

An example output that carries the host/port:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| SNOWFLAKE                                   |
|---------------------------------------------|
| p7b41m.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443 |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

If you're uncertain about what these all mean, you'll need to speak to other, current Snowflake users or administrators in your organization.